# Magento 2 Import PHP library error

Tags: magento2, php, third-party-library, library

I'm trying to import PHP Libraries from SiftScience, 
here is the library that i'm importing, just the lib folder https://github.com/SiftScience/sift-php

I have put this files into `rootmagento/lib/internal/SiftLibrary/SiftMaster`
Then inside that path, i created a `registration.php` file with the following code:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY,
    'SiftLibrary/SiftMaster',
    __DIR__
);
```

When I run the command  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` it throws me this error:

```
Class \Services_JSON does not exist
```

Could it be because JSON.php class is inside a folder `Services_JSON-1.0.3`

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install with composer

`composer require siftscience/sift-php:^4.0`

Then you should be able to pretty much use

`$object = new \SiftClient();` etc